# Cannot access cordova.plugins in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html-framework-7

I have a background mode plugin on my Cordova project, and every time I try accessing it with `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode`, I get the error: `Cannot read property 'backgroundMode' of undefined`.

I went into my main.js file and used `console.log();` to log the variables `cordova` and `cordova.plugins`. `cordova.plugins` returned a value of `undefined`, where `cordova` returned an object. The object however did not contain a `plugins` key, thus explaining the returned `undefined` value.

My code that's trying to access the `cordova` variable does indeed sit within a `deviceready` event. I have also linked to `cordova.js` inside my `index.html` file.

At the top of my main.js file, is where my `deviceready` event handler sits.

```
// The deviceready event.
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    console.log(cordova); // returns an object.
    console.log(cordova.plugins); // returns undefined.

    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable(); // error here at 'cordova.plugins'.
}, false);
```

The background mode plugin I used can be found [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode), along with its documentation.

This is what is printed when I run `cordova plugins ls` in my console(Command Prompt):

```
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
```

To summarize, my Cordova app isn't letting me access the `cordova.plugins` variable as it does not exist under the `cordova` object. I am accessing it inside a `deviceready` event handler and I have linked to the `cordova.js` file inside my `index.html` file.

Comment: did you try reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, Yes I did. I also recreated the project, but I still sat with the same error.

Comment: can you also include the output of `cordova plugin ls` command along with the post please?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, It has been added to my question.